# Converting a non-standard date string to a date

Tags: javascript, php, date, type-conversion

I have a spreadsheet containing 100k dates in the following format:

```
Thursday 29th of October 2015 01:06:21 PM
```

I need to convert these into a useable date format. YYYY/MM/DD, or anything will do. As long as I can get it into a standard format.

I've looked at various PHP/JS date functions, but this date doesn't appear to be recognised. I assume it could be done with some Regex, and I was wondering if anyone has been here before?

Comment: maybe you go ahead and show some *clever* try.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have one :)

Comment: This could be even more easily done in excel btw. Unless you need to automate it a truckload on various other spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace `'of '` with an empty string and use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for it.

```js
var dateString = 'Thursday 29th of October 2015 01:06:21 PM'.replace('of ', ''),
    date = new Date(dateString);

console.log(date);
```

Comment: This also requires that the 'th' be removed, but thanks, it certainly works.

Answer (score 0):

This code will surely helpful for..

```
    var DateObj = new Date()

    function generateDateTOYYMMDD(DateObj){
        var DateDay = DateObj.getDate();
        DateDay = (DateDay<10) ? "0"+DateDay : DateDay;
        var DateMonth = DateObj.getMonth() + 1;
        DateMonth = (DateMonth<10) ? "0"+DateMonth : DateMonth;
        var DateYear = DateObj.getFullYear();
        var DateStr = DateYear + "-" + DateMonth+ "-" + DateDay;
        return DateStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do everything with string.split() and array.indedOf();
Some Examples.

```js
var dateString = "Thursday 29th of October 2015 01:06:21 PM";
var parts = [];
parts = dateString.split(" ");
console.log(parts);
```

```js
var months = ["January", "February","March"];
var monthInt = months.indexOf("March");
console.log(monthInt);
```

after that you just convert to Date

```js
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setMonth(3);
newDate.setDate(15);
newDate.setYear(2016);
console.log(newDate)
```

Comment: special note about month, it counts 0-11 not 1-12

Answer (score 0):

In  PHP,  DateTime::createFromFormat — Returns new DateTime object formatted according to the specified format

```
  $str_date = 'Thursday 29th of October 2015 01:06:21 PM';
    $obj_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $str_date);
    echo date('Y/m/d',$obj_date->getTimestamp());
```

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer as this post has been found in low quality post. Code only and 'try this' answers are discouraged as it doesn't provide any searchable content and why people should 'try this'.